Single UPDATE Postgres query taking more time than batched updates from application code
I have this update query:
UPDATE articlestockhistory
SET articlerotationnature = cross_address_histories.rotation
FROM (
    SELECT
        articlestockhistory.id,
        articlestockhistory.delta,
        CASE
            WHEN articlestockhistory.delta > 0 THEN 'RECEPTION_ONLY_IN_SPECIFIC_STOCK_ADDRESS'
            ELSE 'CONSUMPTION_ONLY_IN_SPECIFIC_STOCK_ADDRESS' END
        AS rotation
    FROM stockmovementline
    INNER JOIN stocklocation source_location on stockmovementline.sourcephysicallocation_id = source_location.id
    INNER JOIN stockwarehouse source_warehouse ON source_location.warehouse_id = source_warehouse.id
    INNER JOIN stocklocation target_location on stockmovementline.targetphysicallocation_id = target_location.id
    INNER JOIN stockwarehouse target_warehouse ON target_location.warehouse_id = target_warehouse.id
    INNER JOIN articlestockhistory ON articlestockhistory.stockchangecauserid = stockmovementline.id
    WHERE
            source_warehouse.address_id != target_warehouse.address_id
      AND articlerotationoverriddenby_id IS NULL
) AS cross_address_histories
WHERE articlestockhistory.id = cross_address_histories.id;

This hits about 3M records of the 27M records I have in articlestockhistory.
Now, I've tried running this and have kept in running for 40 minutes. I see a lot of CPU and disk usage by postgres the whole time, but the query doesn't finish.
If I dropped all indexes on the articlestockhistory table, it finished in about 4 minutes. But this is not feasible in production.
I then converted this UPDATE query to application code:

Run the SELECT query, selecting all 3M rows to application memory
Execute UPDATE queries using JDBC's PreparedStatement with methods addBatch and executeBatch every 10000 records.

This finished in about 15 minutes, and I could view progress while it was running.
This is on a local database which received no other queries.
I don't understand why I'm forced to write application code to do the same updates efficiently. Any insights?

As it stands, you only asked "why I'm forced to write application code to do the same updates" - you're not. If you're trying to figure out why the methods you described perform differently, prepend explain analyze verbose to each version of your query and it'll become clearer what they do and how, as well as where that time went. It would be easier for others to look into it if you shared the output of those explains along with DDL, some sample data and row counts. That way others could reproduce the problem and come up with alternatives to your query.

It could be any number of reasons.  It often comes down to now knowing in advance how many rows will be updated or how much memory it will take and so needing to be defensive.  Insights are contained within the EXPLAIN plan.  If it is too slow to ever finish, you will need to do just EXPLAIN.  If it can finish but just much slower than you would like, then EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) is much better.  We also need to know the version of PostgreSQL.

Hi @Zegarek, thanks for your reply. I've tried running EXPLAIN ANALYZE, which after a while starts emitting "WARNING out of shared memory".
The SELECT query itself runs fine and returns in about 20 seconds.
I'm running on postgres 9.6, but will try it on version 16.

Another approach would be to use CTE to select and update the corresponding rows in one statement and then evaluate the performance
WITH cross_address_histories AS (
   SELECT
        articlestockhistory.id,
        articlestockhistory.delta,
        CASE
            WHEN articlestockhistory.delta > 0 THEN 'RECEPTION_ONLY_IN_SPECIFIC_STOCK_ADDRESS'
            ELSE 'CONSUMPTION_ONLY_IN_SPECIFIC_STOCK_ADDRESS' END
        AS rotation
    FROM stockmovementline
    INNER JOIN stocklocation source_location on stockmovementline.sourcephysicallocation_id = source_location.id
    INNER JOIN stockwarehouse source_warehouse ON source_location.warehouse_id = source_warehouse.id
    INNER JOIN stocklocation target_location on stockmovementline.targetphysicallocation_id = target_location.id
    INNER JOIN stockwarehouse target_warehouse ON target_location.warehouse_id = target_warehouse.id
    INNER JOIN articlestockhistory ON articlestockhistory.stockchangecauserid = stockmovementline.id
    WHERE
            source_warehouse.address_id != target_warehouse.address_id
      AND articlerotationoverriddenby_id IS NULL
)
UPDATE articlestockhistory update_articlestockhistory
SET articlerotationnature = cross_address_histories.rotation
FROM cross_address_histories
WHERE update_articlestockhistory.id = cross_address_histories.id


Postgres rewrites and tries to optimise queries before preparing an execution plan, and moving CTEs and subqueries around is one of the basic tricks it tries - swapping a subquery for a CTE or vice versa is unlikely to make any difference. What might make a difference is forcing it to materialize it: WITH cross_address_histories AS MATERIALIZED(..)UPDATE.. (or, if it already does that, you can try forcing it to not do that).
